# Can someone explain equality to me in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, equality, quote

So I stumbled across this today and it has me puzzled.

```
(define (x) '(1))
(eq? (x) (x))             ;=> #t
(eq? '(1) '(1))           ;=> #f


(define (y) (list 1))
(eq? (y) (y))             ;=> #f
(eq? (list 1) (list 1))   ;=> #f
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here ?

Answer (score 4):

When compiled this program

```
(define (x) '(1))
(eq? (x) (x))             
(eq? '(1) '(1))
```

is compiled into (something like):

```
(define datum1 '(1))
(define datum2 '(1))
(define datum3 '(1))
(define (x) datum1)
(eq? (x) (x))             
(eq? datum2 datum3)
```

Therefore `(x)` will always return the object stored in `datum1`.
The expressions `(eq? '(1) '(1))` on the other hand will
find out that `datum2` and `datum3` does not store the same object.

Note: There is a choice for the compiler writer. Many Scheme implementation will compile the above program to:

```
(define datum1 '(1))
(define (x) datum1)
(eq? (x) (x))             
(eq? datum1 datum1)
```

and then the result will be true in both cases.

Note: The documentation of `quote` doesn't explicitly state whether multiple occurrences of `'(1)` in a program will produce the same value or not. Therefore this behavior might change in the future. [Although I believe the current behavior is a deliberate choice]

Answer (score 3):

[eq?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=eq%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq~3f%29%29) checks if the objects are the same (think "if the pointer refers to the same address in memory").

In the first case you're working with literals created at compile time. Comparing (and modifying) literals is generally undefined behaviour. Here it looks like procedure `x` returns the same literal every time, but in the second expression it looks like the 2 literals are not the same. As I said, undefined behaviour.

In the second case you're not working with literals but `list` creates a new list at execution time. So each call to `y` or `list` creates a fresh list.

Comment: I would, as explained in my answer, clarify the comparing vs modifying of literals: comparing literals may give you unexpected results, but won't actually cause nasal demons, whereas modifying literals is totally nasal demon territory.

Answer (score 2):

uselpa's answer is correct.<sup>†</sup> I wanted to expand on what a quoted datum is, a little further, though.

As you know, all Scheme programs are internally read in as a syntax tree. In Racket, in particular, you use the `read-syntax` procedure to do it:

```
> (define stx (with-input-from-string "(foo bar)" read-syntax))
> stx
#<syntax::1 (foo bar)>
```

You can convert a syntax tree to a datum using `syntax->datum`:

```
> (syntax->datum stx)
'(foo bar)
```

`quote` is a special form, and what it does is return the quoted portion of the syntax tree as a datum. This is why, for many Scheme implementations, your `x` procedure returns the same object each time: it's returning the same portion of the syntax tree as a datum. (This is an implementation detail, and Scheme implementations are not required to have this behaviour, but it helps explain why you see what you see.)

And as uselpa's answer says, `list` creates a fresh list each time, if the list is non-empty. That's why the result of two separate non-empty invocations of `list` will always be distinct when compared with `eq?`.

(In Scheme, the empty list is required to be represented as a singleton object. So `(eq? '() '())` is guaranteed to be true, as is `(eq? (list) '())`, `(eq? (cdr (list 'foo)) (list))`, etc.)

<sup>†</sup> I would not use the phrasing "undefined behaviour" for *comparing* literals because that's easily confused with the C and C++ meaning of UB, which is [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), and although the result of comparing literals may not be what you expect, it would not cause your program to crash, etc. *Modifying* literals is nasal demons, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation, but it only creates more questions for me. I  guess I really don't understand quoting :( I'm a veteran in several other languages (javascript, ruby, php). Is there a similar mechanism in those languages?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is a general term, not restricted to modification of literals. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @naomik JS, Ruby, and PHP are not homoiconic ("code is data") languages, so they don't have a quoting facility. My favourite explanation of `quote` is to go into "data mode", where the quoted stuff is treated as data rather than as code. Feel free to ask more questions to help things make sense—I really want to help. :-)

Comment: @naomik I especially like the approach taken by The Little Schemer books, where code and data are rendered in different fonts. It makes it immediately visually obvious which is which. Anyway, any time you want to embed data in code, you'd use `quote`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young interesting. I sincerely appreciate you eagerness/willingness to help. Since our last encounter, I've added your blog to my subscriptions. I'm currently working through *SICP* but haven't come across quoting yet. *The Little Schemer* is also on my to-read list, but haven't gotten that far. I suppose I'll keep working through my materials and see what questions remain after getting further in my learning.